# How to apply 2-pass postprocessing without using EffectComposer?

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I need to post-process the scene that I rendered previously on textureA (as render target), with my custom shader and save the result to textureB (input:textureA, output:textureB). Therefore, I don't need a scene and a camera. I think it's too simple to even bother with three.js classes like EffectComposer, Shaderpass, CopyShader, TexturePass, etc.

So, how do I setup this computing-like post-processing in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

I've create for you a fiddle that shows a basic post-processing effect without `EffectComposer`. The idea behind this code is to work with an instance of [WebGLRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget).

First, you draw the scene into this render target. In the next step, you use this render target as a texture for a plane which is rendered with an orthographic camera. The code in the render loop looks like this:

```
renderer.clear();

renderer.render( scene, camera, renderTarget );

renderer.render( sceneFX, cameraFX );
```

The corresponding material of this plane is your custom shader. I've used a luminosity shader from the official repo.

> Therefore, I don't need a scene and a camera.

Please do it like in the example. That's the intended way of the library.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/5149/

`three.js R91`

Comment: Thanks, but that is NOT what I asked. Like I wrote above, I have already rendered a scene to textureA and I want to post process it by rendering it to textureB (without EffectComposer), NOT to the screen.
Every example shows what you showed above. I have already implemented the last step to the screen, but I need an ***intermediate*** step, where the textureA is input to post-processing shader and textureB is output (because I need a two-pass postprocessing).
That is why I said I don't need a scene and a camera.

Comment: I edited the title and the text to make it more clear.